# Mix texture and transparent image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I've been asked to do a small animation for a multi story ice cream store. I want to have a steel background texture with a transparent image of an ice cream on just the front face of the elevator door. Most solutions I've read through mention unwrapping the face, but that gives me the following message: 
"Object has non-uniform scale, unwrap will operate on a non-scaled version of the mesh". The transparent image also applies itself to all faces of the door.

[image: This] This is what I have. And this[image: This] is what I want. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance,

Joe

Comment: Apply scale before doing UV unwrap. Select in object mode and press *ctrl+A*, choose *Scale*. Or click *Object->Apply->Scale*

Comment: I've applied scale before unwrapping and I did not get the message this time round. I also got the image where I want, however it's still on all faces and stretched out. ![stretchy image](http://i.imgur.com/2buGGhB.png)

Comment: You are using a bit old Blender version. Nowaday it is 2.78a. This node for example has additional rollout for image mapping type. http://imgur.com/mqDNwTH

Comment: Maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your unwrapping is the reason. You have unwrapped the faces so that they are overlapping. In the Image Editor, while unwrapping, try moving the faces so that they are not overlapping. Then when you add the transparent image make sure to tweak the Mapping node so that you offset it where it needs to be. 
I hope this helps.